# Passing a derived class containing an overloaded property as a parameter

Tags: vb.net

I have two objects, one is a base class and the other is a derived class which inherits the base class. One of the properties on the derived class overloads a property on the base class. Now, I want to perform some calculations on both of these objects one by one by passing them as a parameter into a function. The problem is, if I define the parameter of this function as a base class, then when passing the derived class, the value of the overloaded property gets lost!

The reason I'm using a derived class is to temporarily add more properties/modify the existing properties of the base class to perform additional calculations, in order to reuse the base class.

I've tried 4 different functions, but none of them are any good. They either don't work correctly, or there is duplicate code, which I need to avoid because there will be a lot more code later. Below is the pseudo code.

**Defining the classes:**

```
Class BaseClass
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Value As Integer
End Class

Class DerivedClass
    Inherits BaseClass
    Overloads Property Value As Double
End Class
```

**Initializing:**

```
Dim MyBaseObject As New BaseClass()
MyBaseObject.Name = NameOf(MyBaseObject)
MyBaseObject.Value = 5

Dim MyDerivedObject As New DerivedClass
MyDerivedObject.Name = NameOf(MyDerivedObject)
MyDerivedObject.Value = 5.3
```

**Calling the functions:**

```
ProcessClass1(MyBaseObject)
ProcessClass1(MyDerivedObject)

ProcessClass2(MyBaseObject)
ProcessClass2(MyDerivedObject)

ProcessClass3(MyBaseObject)
ProcessClass3(MyDerivedObject)

ProcessClass4(MyBaseObject)
ProcessClass4(MyDerivedObject)
```

**The functions:**

```
Sub ProcessClass1(inClass As Object) 'functions correctly, but no intellisense
    Console.WriteLine(inClass.Name & " " & inClass.Value)
End Sub

Sub ProcessClass2(inClass As BaseClass) 'does not function correctly, but has intellisense
    Console.WriteLine(inClass.Name & " " & inClass.Value) 'Value displays 0 when passing MyDerivedObject, it should be 5.3!
End Sub

Sub ProcessClass3(inClass As Object) 'functions correctly, has intellisense, but need to write code for all possible derived types in advance

    If inClass.GetType = GetType(BaseClass) Then
        Dim inBaseClass As BaseClass = inClass
        Console.WriteLine(inBaseClass.Name & " " & inBaseClass.Value)
    End If

    If inClass.GetType = GetType(DerivedClass) Then
        Dim inDerivedClass As DerivedClass = inClass
        Console.WriteLine(inDerivedClass.Name & " " & inDerivedClass.Value)
    End If

End Sub

Sub ProcessClass4(inClass As BaseClass) 'method overloading: functions correctly, has intellisense, but need to write a duplicate method for every derived type
    Console.WriteLine(inClass.Name & " " & inClass.Value)
End Sub
Sub ProcessClass4(inClass As DerivedClass) 'method overloading: functions correctly, has intellisense, but need to write a duplicate method for every derived type
    Console.WriteLine(inClass.Name & " " & inClass.Value)
End Sub
```

**Extra: Generics**
I don't see any advantage with generics, the below snipped runs into the same problem as ProcessClass2:

```
Dim MyProcessGenericObject As New ProcessGenericClass(Of BaseClass)

MyProcessGenericObject.processNewItem(MyBaseObject)
MyProcessGenericObject.processNewItem(MyDerivedObject)

Public Class ProcessGenericClass(Of T As BaseClass)
    Public Sub processNewItem(ByVal newItem As T)
        Console.WriteLine(newItem.Name & " " & newItem.Value) 'Value displays 0 when passing MyDerivedObject!
    End Sub
End Class
```

Of these 4 functions, ProcessClass1 is the most elegant with the least amount of code, but there is no intellisense on inClass which makes it impossible to maintain.

What I need is no duplication of code, intellisense, a method which can take derived classes inherited from the same base class, and without losing the data contained in any overloaded properties. What would be the best way to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you sow how values of base and derived classes would be used in the `ProcessClass` function?

Comment: When you start facing problem with inheritance - this is usually a good sign that inheritance isn't right approach for the problem.

Comment: I don't think you can change the type (from Int to Double) when overriding

Comment: you're trying to use the same class / subclass structure to process different data types. if that is all you are after, try using generics to accomplish the same task (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/)

Comment: @Jeremy I've tried generics, but I get the same problems as with the functions. See the updated post with example.

Comment: Your generic example is parameterized by the base class; that will never work.  You might be able to use a generic function (not  a class), depending on why it is that you want this type arrangement in the first place.  If the goal is to be able to save typing, then this may work.  If the goal is to do dynamic dispatch where at the time of trying to call the function, you don't know its runtime type (only that it derives from the base), then it definitely won't work.

Comment: If what you need is dynamic dispatch, then the result will necessarily be ugly, because .NET only supports dynamic dispatch where the signature in the derived class matches the signature in the base class.  You would need to make `Value` have type `Object` and then convert into a suitable combined type in the processing code (and you would get a runtime error if an implementation were not convertible into your merged type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have put forward will not work with the instance you pass around being the base class. That instance's value property will always be an integer unless you are able to cast the instance to the appropriate derived class (and that (double)int cast is where you have lost precision).

But a combination of some of these generics may help. Note, the base class will not hold an integer, rather an Object.

```
Public Class BaseClass
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Value As Object
End Class

Public Class BaseClass(Of T)
    Inherits BaseClass
    Public Overloads Property Value As T
        Get
            Return CType(MyBase.Value, T)
        End Get
        Set(value As T)
            MyBase.Value = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Class DerivedClassDouble
    Inherits BaseClass(Of Double)
End Class

Class DerivedClassInteger
    Inherits BaseClass(Of Integer)
End Class
```

The process method

```
Sub ProcessClass(inClass As BaseClass)
    Console.WriteLine($"{inClass.Name} {inClass.Value}")
End Sub
```

Some options for instantiation

```
Dim [myBase] As New BaseClass()
[myBase].Name = NameOf([myBase])
[myBase].Value = 5

Dim myBaseInteger As New BaseClass(Of Integer)
myBaseInteger.Name = NameOf(myBaseInteger)
myBaseInteger.Value = 5

Dim myDerivedInteger As New DerivedClassInteger
myDerivedInteger.Name = NameOf(myDerivedInteger)
myDerivedInteger.Value = 5

Dim myBaseDouble As New BaseClass(Of Double)
myBaseDouble.Name = NameOf(myBaseDouble)
myBaseDouble.Value = 5.3

Dim myDerivedDouble As New DerivedClassDouble
myDerivedDouble.Name = NameOf(myDerivedDouble)
myDerivedDouble.Value = 5.3

ProcessClass([myBase])
ProcessClass(myBaseInteger)
ProcessClass(myDerivedInteger)
ProcessClass(myBaseDouble)
ProcessClass(myDerivedDouble)

Console.ReadLine()
```

> myBase 5
>   
> myBaseInteger 5
>   
> myDerivedInteger 5
>   
> myBaseDouble 5.3
>   
> myDerivedDouble 5.3

I think the closest to your implementation would be to use `[myBase]` and `myDerivedDouble` instances. Then changing the generic base class to `Public MustInherit Class BaseClass(Of T)` would make the intent clearer.

Hopefully last edit, sorry for the long-winded answer.

You can just change your original classes to have an object in the base class, and use the property implementation I laid out, and that seems to get the job done without any generics. Again, it may or may not work in your exact implementation

```
Sub Main()
    Dim MyBaseObject As New BaseClass()
    MyBaseObject.Name = NameOf(MyBaseObject)
    MyBaseObject.Value = 5

    Dim MyDerivedObject As New DerivedClass
    MyDerivedObject.Name = NameOf(MyDerivedObject)
    MyDerivedObject.Value = 5.3

    ProcessClass(MyBaseObject)
    ProcessClass(MyDerivedObject)

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Sub ProcessClass(inClass As BaseClass)
    Console.WriteLine($"{inClass.Name} {inClass.Value}")
End Sub

Public Class BaseClass
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Value As Object
End Class

Public Class DerivedClass
    Inherits BaseClass
    Overloads Property Value As Double
        Get
            Return CDbl(MyBase.Value)
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            MyBase.Value = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

> MyBaseObject 5
>   
> MyDerivedObject 5.3